# How to reduce column width in table with selenium driver

Tags: java, selenium

I am automating one functionality on certain website where I want to resize the column 'Description' of table, but while doing same with below mentioned code, getting some kind of warning or error and same is not happening.

//This is Description column for which I want to change the width

```
    WebElement descr = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Description"));

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 25);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Description")));

    int width_descr = descr.getSize().getWidth();
    int height_descr = descr.getSize().getHeight();
    System.out.println("Width of Description ="+width_descr);
    System.out.println("Height of Description ="+height_descr);

    int half_height_descr= height_descr/2;
    System.out.println("Half of Height of Description ="+half_height_descr);

    //Logger.getLogger("org.openqa.selenium").setLevel(Level.SEVERE);

    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

    Action resizable = builder
            .moveToElement(descr, width_descr, height_descr)
            .clickAndHold()
            .moveByOffset(width_descr, 0)
            .release()
            .build();

    resizable.perform();

}
```

Actual output as below:-

```
Width of Description =242
Height of Description =27
Half of Height of Description =13
```

Apr 01, 2019 8:35:54 PM org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions moveToElement

INFO: When using the W3C Action commands, offsets are from the center of element--This is the warning i am getting in console.

and column width not getting reduced on UI.

Expected output:- I want to reduce the column width.

Comment: Does it need to be done in a manual way? Are you testing something that happens once you resize it? Or do you just need to resize it, and it doesn't matter how it is done?

Comment: You are attempting to resize the "Description" *link*... not the column heading. If you want help with this, you will have to (preferably) provide a link to the page or at least the relevant HTML of the column heading. I'm assuming you need to click on the border between two column headings and then slide it over.

Comment: @Asyranok :- Yes, it doesn't matter. Just somehow I want to reduce column width. But not manually.

Comment: Can you attach the html of the table and specify the column you want to modify the width of? With that information, resizing it will be extremely simple.

Comment: @JeffC: You are correct, i wanted to click on the border between two column headings and then slide it over.

Comment: Html code for table:-
<div id="InvoiceTranGrid_3" data-role="grid" class="k-grid k-widget k-editable" style="touch-action: pan-y;">
<div class="k-header k-grid-toolbar">
<button id="PostInvoicePayment_3" class="k-button" onclick="return addInvoiceTransaction(3)" style="">Post Activity</button>
<button id="ChargeCorrection_3" class="k-button" onclick="return addChargeCorrectionInvoice(&quot;Paragon&quot;, &quot;0000000002&quot;, &quot;125062&quot;, 3)" style="display: none;">Charge Correction</button>
</div>
<table role="treegrid">

Comment: Html code for element:-
<th scope="col" role="columnheader" data-field="PayCodeDescription" rowspan="1" data-title="Description" data-index="6" id="481be08a-993c-4890-9df3-1d387c2dbd74" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter">
<a class="k-link" href="#">Description</a>
</th>

Comment: Please edit the question and post the HTML there, properly formatted. This is likely not something that we are going to be able to solve without a link to the page or at least a demo page. I'm assuming this is going to be very tricky.

Answer (score 0):

If this is HTML5 form - you cannot do that with Actions class as well as with Robot framework.

You can try to make screenshot of web element and interact it with Sikuli library, e.g.: https://github.com/alexandrchumakin/Relay42ApiTest/blob/master/src/main/java/web/driver/WebDriverHelper.java#L35

Or you can implement JQuery that will do all this magic.